# Setting values previously set in controller on nested_attributes via model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I was previously adding my current user id to my tracks via the track controller's create method using:

```
@track.user_id = current_user.id
```

This worked fine, however, i've now nested tracks within my releases model and am trying to do the same via callbacks in my releases model using:

```
before_save :add_user_to_tracks
before_update :add_user_to_tracks

def add_user_to_tracks
  tracks.each { |t| t.user_id = self.current_user.id}
end
```

I get an **undefined method `current_user'** error, however, I know this is very close to working as if I test it using "99" instead of self.current_user.id it adds 99 to the user_id for each track in the db.

Any ideas why I can't access **current_user.id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should send user_id from your form using hidden field.

If you don't have user_id in Release model. You can create it as virtual attribute.

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :user_id

  before_save :add_user_to_tracks 
  before_update :add_user_to_tracks

  def add_user_to_tracks
    tracks.each { |t| t.user_id = user_id}
  end
end
```

Comment: User_id is from Devise so I was hoping it would be available globally? I will give your suggestion a go though. Thanks!

Comment: You can use current_user helper only on Controller and View layer not in Models

Comment: But I am afraid you have wrong whole saving concept and your tracks will not be save. But that only my feeling. :)

Comment: I have this before the code I posted and from my understanding this will save the tracks for me: accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true

Comment: Yes thats the right way but i think it is not so easy. Anyway good luck :)

Comment: It's working, thank you! Now onto all the other problems with this app!!